# ¿Se usa o ha usado la expresión "estar las manos en la masa" como sinónimo de "estar a punto de morir"?

Tags: expresiones, significado, adverbios, locuciones

La locución adverbial *[con las manos en la masa](https://dle.rae.es/mano#ByNFQcv)* significa, según el DLE, "en el momento de estar haciendo algo". Esta expresión viene de muy antiguo, de hecho ya en el diccionario de Covarrubias de 1611 se menciona la expresión *traer las manos en la masa* con el significado de "andar metido en algún negocio".

Sin embargo, buscando ejemplos en el CORDE me encuentro con que el amigo Korreas menciona la expresión en su peculiar *Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales* de 1627:

> "Kon las manos en la masa."
>
> Estar en ofizio komenzado obra.

Hasta aquí bien, pero también menciona lo siguiente:

> "Estar kon las manos en la masa."
>
> Lo ke: "Estar las manos en la masa".
>
> Estar para espirar.
>
> Denotando mucha angustia o flakeza.

Los diccionarios de la época recogen la voz *espirar* como sinónimo de "morir", con el significado de "rendir el alma, dar la postrera boqueada", como cita el propio Covarrubias. El caso es que estoy buscando en otros diccionarios por si veía ese significado citado por Korreas, y textos de la época en el CORDE que incluyan las palabras "manos" y "masa" o "massa", y no veo ninguno en el que la expresión claramente signifique "estar para morir".

¿Realmente significó la expresión *las manos en la masa* "estar para morir"? ¿Hay textos que muestren claramente este significado? ¿O pudo ser un desliz del señor Korreas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que has interpretado mal el resultado de la búsqueda. Yo lo entiendo así (negritas mías, palabras en [corchetes] mías):

> **"Estar kon las manos en la masa."**

> [Significa] Lo [mismo] ke: "Estar las manos en la masa".

> **Estar para espirar.**

> Denotando mucha angustia o flakeza.

es decir: "**Estar con las manos en la masa**" significa lo mismo que "estar las manos en la masa" (es decir, las palabras "lo ke" significan algo como "véase"). "**Estar para espirar**" sería la siguiente entrada, cuyo significado sería "Denotando mucha angustia o flakeza". Las dos entradas no estarían relacionadas.

Si observas la correspondiente [página de resultados del CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=0&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=220920%5C010%5CC000O22092020101426300.1020.1016&desc=%7BB%7D%20%7BI%7D%20kon%20las%20manos%20en%20la%20masa%7B%7CI%7D,%20en%20todos%20los%20medios,%20en%20%7BI%7DCORDE%20%7B%7CI%7D%20%7B%7CB%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto0), verás que el formato es ese: una expresión en una línea, su explicación en la siguiente. Ninguna expresión es explicada en más de una línea. En el texto original, probablemente las expresiones y sus explicaciones tenían distinta fuente o tamaño de letra. [Aquí](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra/vocabulario-de-refranes-y-frases-proverbiales-y-otras-formulas-comunes-de-la-lengua-castellana---van-anedidas-las-declaraciones-y-aplicacion-adonde-parecio-ser-necesaria-al-cabo-se-ponen-las-frases-mas-llenas-y-copiosas/) hay una versión aparentemente actualizada del libro, donde se ve también este formato.

Comment: Una vez revisado el ejemplar que me has enlazado, efectivamente he malinterpretado el resultado de la búsqueda del CORDE. Las entradas no tenían nada que ver la una con la otra.

Comment: De las dos preguntas que hice ayer, una resultó que era duplicada de otra, y la otra ha resultado que no tenía sentido porque ha sido una malinterpretación de un texto, definitivamente no fue mi mejor día... :-D

Comment: @Charlie sigue siendo mucho mejor que no hacer ninguna pregunta ;)

Answer (score -1):

Con "las manos en la masa" para nada significa "estar para morir".
Con "las manos en la masa" quiere decir "haciendo algo con las manos en el acto/en el momento".
Ejemplos:
dos choros estan robando un grifo y sacando el dinero de la caja y justo llega la policia.
Esto quiere decir que "la policia los encontro con las manos en la masa" osea robando!

Comment: Bienvenido a nuestro sitio, Freddy Daniel. El uso actual de la expresión "con las manos en la masa" está bastante claro, y la definición del diccionario y tu ejemplo así lo demuestran. Sin embargo, el libro que encontré que propone un significado diferente es de 1627, hace casi 4 siglos. Luego es posible que por aquel entonces se usara con ese otro significado propuesto, o incluso que se siga usando así en alguna parte del mundo hispanohablante. Eso es lo que estoy buscando, si en alguna parte y/o en algún momento de la historia se usó con el significado propuesto por Korreas en el siglo XVII.